# "Invitations" link is offset on Stack Overflow Careers

Tags: bug, status-completed, jobs, design, user-interface

The "invitations" link seems to be vertically offset from other nav links on all SO Careers pages.

[image]

I've tried the simple things, like zooming in and out on the browser, and it's always offset. I'm using IE 11.0.9600.17498 on Windows 8.1.

I'd be lying to say I wasn't a bit confused. I'm no expert in CSS, but I'm not seeing anything obvious that could cause this.

It's also worth noting that the `:hover` effect seems to be applying "properly," relative to the text. The whole `span` seems just to be shifted down.

Comment: Thanks for bringing this to our attention. Looking into it!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This has been fixed. For some reason, IE11 style precedence behaves differently from other browsers, and was incorrectly selecting

```
vertical-align: text-top;
```

instead of

```
vertical-align: top;
```

I added a more specific class to avoid this issue, IE11 should be happier now.

Thanks for reporting this issue :)

Comment: "For some reason" - Microsoft don't need reason. They never followed standards, and never will.